# How to create combinations with constrains in Python

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have a list of football players. Each player has three attributes: position (G, D, M, A), name and salary.

```
Position Name     Salary
P        Buffon    6
D        Maldini  23
D        Baresi   15
D        Bergomi   7
C        Kakà     33
C        Gomez    18
A        Ronaldo  52
A        Vieri    44
...
```

I want to create all possible combinations of a football team which contains exactly 11 players. These are the constrains:

1. Players constrain: total elements = 11
2. Position constrain: P = 1, D = 4, C = 4, A = 2
3. Salary constrain: sum salary < 200

I have started researching and it looks to me that itertools could help me generate all possible teams given the constrains. But what is not clear to me is how to code the constrains.

```
subset = df[['position', 'name', 'salary']]
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
all_permutations = itertools.permutations(tuples)
for perm in all_permutations:
    # constrains
```

Comment: This is a complex problem, do you need to solve it "optimally" from an algorithm point of view?

Comment: No, I just need to list all possible permutations given the above constrains. For each combination of exactly 11 players I check if all constrains are OK. If yes, I store the solution, otherwise I discard.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean combinations, not permutations, as the order in which you place the players on a team is irrelevant

Comment: You are right, let me edit the question

Comment: What is the domain of roster size? Please also include some sample rosters you plan to verify with. Are all players single position players?

Comment: If your (P, D, C, A) values are fixed, then find all combinations of individual P, D, C, and A. Then take the product of those combinations. Then filter out the final result based on the salary constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The itertools library has a very nice function for iterating through combinations. You can get all combinations of 11 players, and then filter through those.

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools

def valid_team(team):
    positions = []
    salary = 0
    for player in team:
        (player_pos,_,player_salary)=player
        positions.append(player_pos)
        salary += player_salary
    pos_count = Counter(positions)
    return (
        pos_count['P'] is 1 and
        pos_count['D'] is 4 and
        pos_count['C'] is 4 and
        pos_count['A'] is 2 and
        salary<200
    )

for team in itertools.combinations(players,11):
    if (valid_team(team)):
        print("found valid team")
        print(team)
    else:
        print("found invalid team")
```

It should be noted that there is lot of unnecessary processing in the above method, as you can select each position individually. Alternative implementation below.

```
players_sorted = {}
for player in players:
    if player[0] not in players_sorted:
        players_sorted[player[0]] = []
    players_sorted[player[0]].append(player)

p_guys = itertools.combinations(players_sorted['P'],1)
d_guys = itertools.combinations(players_sorted['D'],4)
c_guys = itertools.combinations(players_sorted['C'],4)
a_guys = itertools.combinations(players_sorted['A'],2)

teams = itertools.product(p_guys,d_guys,c_guys,a_guys)

for team in teams:
    team_players = []
    for pos in team:
        team_players.extend(pos)
    if (valid_team(team_players)):
        print("found valid team")
        print(team)
    else:
        print("found invalid team")
        print(team)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple recursion with a generator:

```
from collections import Counter
pos_c = {'P':1, 'D':4, 'C':4, 'A':2}
def teams(d, c = []):
  if len(c) == 11:
    yield c
  else:
    s, pos = sum(int(j) for *_, j in c), Counter([j for j, *_ in c])
    for i in d:
       if not c or (i not in c and s+int(i[-1]) < 200 and pos_c[i[0]] >= pos.get(i[0], 0)+1):
         yield from teams(d, c+[i])
```